# Where can I find a list of `property`s for wdSetProperty (R package R2wd)

Tags: r, com, ms-word

I want to change the font for `Complex Script` for Right-to-Left languages (such as Arabic and Persian) in wdSetProperty but I do not know how to find the name for this property. Where should I find a list of properties available in COM connection to MS-Word?

```
require(R2wd)

wdGet()
wdTitle("Title")
wdBody("This is in normal font")
wdSetProperty(c("Font","Name"),"Garamond")
wdSetProperty(c("Font","Size"),20)
wdWrite("This is in 14pt Garamond\n")
wdNormal("This switches back to Normal")

wdBody("تست")
wdSetProperty(c("Font","Name"),"XB Niloofar")
wdSetProperty(c("Font","Size"),20)
wdWrite("سلام\n")
wdNormal("تست")
```

As you can see the example above has changed the font for Latin font not the font for complex script.

[image: Font for Latin Text Changed not for Complex Script]

I also want the `direction` (right-to-left vs. left-to-right) property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround for my problem, but I would like to find a complete reference on this.

To find the names for properties I wanted I did this:

- Open a New Document in Word
- Write a paragraph without setting direction or fonts
- Record a new macro from Developer tab, Code section:
  [image]
- select the paragraph and click the bottom-right arrow in the Font section:
  [image]
- change the font for complex script
- click bottom-right arrow in Paragraph section
  [image]
- change the direction for paragraph
- stop recording macro
- see the `VBA` code for this macro

This way I found out that:

- Font for Complex Script is changed via `Font.NameBi`
- Paragraph Direction `ParagraphFormat.ReadingOrder`

Thus, the answer to my question is: (0 is for RTL and 1 for LTR in `ReadingOrder`)

```
require(R2wd)

wdGet()

wdBody("تست")
wdSetProperty(c("Font","NameBi"),"XB Niloofar")
wdSetProperty(c("Font","Size"),20)
wdSetProperty(c("ParagraphFormat","ReadingOrder"),0)
wdWrite("سلام\n")
wdNormal("تست")
```

Comment: I doubt if there is much more, reference-wise, than in the MSDN library, e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word._paragraphformat.readingorder(v=office.11).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdreadingorder(v=office.14).aspx . You can usually find the enumeration constants in the Visual Basic Editor View->Object Browser, but that browser does not usually explain what the properties are actually for.